# Sequence of ideals in C*-algebra such that its intersection are not zero but intersection of dense sets are zero

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $$A_0 \supset A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset\ldots$$ be a sequence of $C^*$-algebras, such that $A_n$ is an ideal in $A_m$ (while $n>m$), and $K_i \subset A_i$ be a dense ${}^*$-subalgebra in $A_i$, such that $$K_0 \supset K_1 \supset K_2 \supset K_3 \supset\ldots$$ Is it possible, that $\bigcap_i K_i = 0$ but $\bigcap A_i \neq 0$? I know that it's possible if the condition "$A_i$ is a $C^*$-algebra" [replaced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713102/sequence-of-dense-sets-in-banach-spaces) by "$A_i$ is a Banach space", so I think it's possible, but I can't construct an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A = C([0,1], \mathbb{C})$ and let every $A_i$ equal $A$.  Let $f \in A$ be any strictly positive one-to-one function; for instance, $f(x) = 1+x$ would do.  Let $K_i$ be the *-subalgebra of $A$ generated by the function $f^{2^i}$, that is, all functions of the form
$$g(x) = a_1 f(x)^{2^i} + a_2 f(x)^{2 \cdot 2^i} + \dots + a_n f(x)^{n \cdot 2^i}, \quad a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}, \quad n \ge 1.$$
Clearly $K_i \supset K_{i+1}$.  Also, since $f$ is one-to-one and positive, so is $f^{2^i}$.  Thus $K_i$ separates points and vanishes nowhere so by Stone-Weierstrass $K_i$ is dense in $A$.  Yet the intersection of all $K_i$ is just 0.

Comment: Little misunderstanding. I know Stone-Weierstrass theorem in next formulation: every subalgebra of $C([0..1])$ that contains unity and separates points dense in $C([0..1])$, your $K_i$ separates points, but what about unity?

Comment: @kp9r4d: The 'vanishes nowhere" condition can substitute for that.  See https://math.la.asu.edu/~quigg/teach/courses/571/2005spring/notes/stone.pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer!